# Find directories with file match 1 but not file match 2

Tags: windows, windows-search

I feel like I should have been able to find this with simple googling/searching here but haven't managed so... Basically the same as [this question of at AU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370024/find-directories-that-dont-contain-a-file-but-yes-another-one) but for Windows.

I want to find directories that *have* a file with name including (for example) `02` or `03` but *do not* have a file with a name including `01`. I'd prefer a nice CLI command but I'm open to installing anything less than Ubuntu (or other *nix distro).

For example:

```
\music\The Irish Roves\Hardstuff\
    01 - All Sing Together.mp3
    02 - Paddy On The Turnpike.mp3
    ...
    \\shouldn't match that folder
\music\Garth Brooks\Ropin' The Wind\
   03 - What She's DOing Now.mp3
   \\but should match this one
```

Comment: I think the kind of OSs actually capable of doing so _per se_ (i.e. without any 3rd party tools or using only a terminal) are linux or similar based systems. Which you mistakenly generalize as Ubuntu.

Comment: @arielnmz No I'm not saying that's a Ubuntu specific feature - I know that `find` is more or less standard across the nix genera. (How standard I'm not sure and don't really care).

Comment: Well, I guessed that because you said *anything less than Ubuntu* but I see that you've edited it. By the way, have you tried to take a look at the **powershell**?

Comment: @arielnmz Yeah I edited it to make it more clear given your comment. No I haven't, I'll do that, thanks.

Comment: @arielnmz Thanks for the pointer. I figured out a command that works with Powershell to do just that :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out how to do this.

Requires the Microsoft free program [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx). Just install that and then the command is:

Cmd:

```
$a = gci path/to/look/at -r | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | ? {$_.GetFiles().Count -ne 0} 
$a = $a | ? {Test-Path($_.fullname+"\*02*")}  | ? {(Test-Path($_.fullname+"\*01*")) -eq $False} 
$a | select FullName
```

You can also do that as a oneliner but wrote it multiline for easier reading here.

That cmd is also using some shortcuts; `gci` = `Get-ChildItem` and `?` = `Where-Object` and `select` = `SelectObject`.

Thanks to arielnmz for pointing me in the right direction